# CoreData, displaying saved journeys in a tableview

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I am trying to display a list of all journeys recorded in a fitness-style app in a table view to show the distance (boolean) and date (timestamp) of each journey.

At the moment I have just created a variable to contain the Journeys from the core data file. When I print out the journeysArray, it shows 0 in the console even though there are some recorded journeys.

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class SavedJourneysViewController: UITableViewController {

    var journeyArray: [Journey] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        print(journeyArray.count)
        return journeyArray.count

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JourneyItem", for: indexPath)
        return cell

    }
```

Comment: How are you fetching the CoreData? Even if you had data in the journeyArray you aren't doing with it in ` tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt`.

Comment: Are you sure you want to display distance (generally a number) as Boolean (true, false)?

Answer (score 0):

If `Journey` is your `NSManagedObject` subclass, you should use a `NSFetchedResultsController` to fetch the persisted objects.

Your `SavedJourneysViewController` must have a reference to the `NSManagedObjectContext` instance that you'll use to fetch your `Journey` objects. Let's assume that you have a `viewContext` property of type `NSManagedObjectContext` in your `SavedJourneysViewController` that's being set from the outside, wherever you initialize your `SavedJourneysViewController`.

You'll want to declare a `fetchedResultsController` in `SavedJourneysViewController`.

```
private lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Journey> = {
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest< Journey > = Journey.fetchRequest()
    let sortDescriptor = NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Journey.date, ascending: true)
    fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [sortDescriptor]
    let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)
    return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

Then perform fetch in `viewDidLoad` (for example) by calling `try? fetchedResultsController.performFetch()`:

Then in `numberOfRowsInSection` return `fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].objects?.count ?? 0`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections?[section].objects?.count ?? 0
}
```

Don't forget about implementing `func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int` and returning `fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0`:

```
func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return fetchedResultsController.sections?.count ?? 0
}
```

In `cellForRowAt`, configure your cell with a `Journey` object:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "JourneyItem", for: indexPath)
    guard let journey = fetchedResultsController.sections?[indexPath.section].objects?[indexPath.row] as? Journey else {
        return cell
    }
    // handle cell configuration
    cell.textLabel?.text = String(journey.distance)
    return cell
}
```

More about using `NSFetchedResultsController` with `UITableViewController` -

- https://cocoacasts.com/populate-a-table-view-with-nsfetchedresultscontroller-and-swift-3
- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/nsfetchedresultscontroller.html